# Why a object with `value:number` field can't be assigned to the `Partial` of a generic interface with `value:number`

Tags: typescript

Why a object with `value:number` field can't be assigned to the `Partial` of a generic interface with `value:number`

```js
interface ValueNumber {
  value: number;
}

type ValueNumberMaybeUndefined = Partial<ValueNumber>;

function testfunc<T extends ValueNumberMaybeUndefined>() {
  const a: Partial<T> = {
    value: 1,
  };
}
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: `T` could be `{value: undefined}`.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `T` is specified by the caller of the function. `testfunc` therefore does not know the shape of `T` in advance. When you use `T` in a generic type like `Partial`, the expression will essentially be opaque to the compiler and it will not try to evaluate it further making it hard to assign anything to it.

But a type assertion will let you assign something to a variable of type `Partial<T>`.

```
function testfunc<T extends ValueNumberMaybeUndefined>() {
  const a = {
    value: 1,
  } as Partial<T>;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDYFcIDksC2ARtMgN4BQyyAbpjgFzIiElQDcFAvhRWAJ4AHFOmx5W0ALJx%20JAKogAJhBigIi5AF5kABThQwwTAB5ROfMWgA%20ThRhYQCQwHsQySAGcw9x8YAqyBAAHpBKHmj04pZQ0rIQCsqqIOpWABQAlORUyAiuXshwWlnU1HRiTACMADTZXAXhegZGGP423EA)